# jquery .animate within Interval (or timeOut) keeps going after clear

Tags: javascript, audio, jquery-animate, settimeout, setinterval

I am learning JS, working in some code that roughly syncs an audio (spoken voice) with a text (the transcription of the spoken voice).

More concretely the code changes the background color of the text, character by character, in equivalence to ms of playing audio. Additionally you can click on any character of the text to go to the equivalent ms in the audio.

I am using Bart Veneman spanner to automatically add spans to each character on my text, then Jquery to .animate the background color of these characters using a for loop and these spans. The background color .animation takes +-240ms per character to happen.

As audio ontimeupdate seemed not very reliable, I am using an interval as my timer: it starts when audio starts and runs paralel to it. The background color .animation happens within this interval.

**¿What's the problem?** : If you [visit the website](http://jaumeferrete.net/afonica/testInterval) (working under Firefox, not Chrome) and click any part of the text (audio starts playing), then click some other part of the text (audio playing point changes) you will notice that some text characters background color remains. These characters background color is not properly cleared:

**¿What's my guess?** : that this happens because of the +-240ms the background color .animation takes to happen VS how/when I call the clearInterval VS how/when the for loop that clears the background color happens.

**more info** :
The for loop that clears the background color AND the interval, both run within a function that fires when audio.onplay.

When a text character is clicked, audio is paused, playing point is changed, and audio.onplay is fired, so calling that function.

The clearInterval is within the Interval itself, and runs if audio.onpause or on.ended (and also if the last character of the text is reached).

I've read that Intervals loop without waiting that the block of code within them finishes, so I've also tried with a timeout [here](http://jaumeferrete.net/afonica/testTimeout) , with the same results.

¿What is exactly happening?
¿What could be a good way to solve this?

Thank you

full code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es" xml:lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>masculinidades/masculinities TEST 5</title>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="miAudio" preload="auto" controls><source src=audio/talk.mp3 type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

<p id="text">La lógica del empresario criminal, el pensamiento de los
boss coincide con el neoliberalismo más radical. Estar en
situación de decidir sobre la vida y la muerte de todos</p>

<script src="js/spanner.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

      // spanner aplica span .char* en orden creciente al contenido del elemento #text
      spanner( document.getElementById("text") );

      // guardar el elemento audio y el tamaño del texto en  variables
      var elAudio = document.getElementById("miAudio");
      var durText = $("#text").text().length;

      // calcular cada cuantos ms hemos de de avanzar un caracter
      var msXchar = Math.floor((elAudio.duration*1000) / durText);
      console.log("1 Char cada " + msXchar + " ms");


      // al hacer hover en cualquier elemento con clase char(int) colorea y pon cursor
      $("[class^='char']").hover(
         function() {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'e-resize');
            if ($(this).css("backgroundColor") != "rgb(0, 250, 154)") {
               $(this).css("backgroundColor", "rgb(0, 250, 154)");
            } else {
               $(this).css("backgroundColor", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
            };

         }, function() {
            if ($(this).css("backgroundColor") == "rgb(0, 250, 154)") {
               $(this).css("backgroundColor", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
            } else {
               $(this).css("backgroundColor", "rgb(0, 250, 154)");
            };  
         }
      );

      /* al hacer click en cualquier elemento con clase char(int) usa (int) para ir al tiempo del audio equivalente */
      $("[class^='char']").click(
         function() {
            elAudio.pause();
            console.log("clicked paused")

            //extrae el int y escala a tiempo de audio
            var thisChar = $(this).attr('class').substring(4);
            var thisTime = ((thisChar / durText) * (elAudio.duration));

            //muévete a ese tiempo de audio
            elAudio.currentTime = thisTime + (msXchar*2/1000)
            console.log(thisChar, thisTime);
            elAudio.play();
         }
      );


      // cuando se hace play al audio ...
      elAudio.onplay = function() {

            console.log("onplay");

            // + borra todo caracter coloreado
            for (var i = 0; i < (durText+1); i++) {
               $(".char" + i).css("backgroundColor", "#ffffff")
            };

            // en qué MILIsegundo del audio estamos y a q equivale en texto?
            var actualTime = Math.floor(elAudio.currentTime*1000);
            var actualChar = Math.floor(((actualTime/1000) / elAudio.duration) * (durText));
            console.log("start " + "ms: " + actualTime , "char: " + actualChar);


             // ... inicia un Interval que avanza paralelamente al audio
            var elInterval = setInterval(function(){

               // colorea el actual char
               console.log("start colorea")
               $( ".char" + actualChar).animate({ 
                  backgroundColor: '#00fa9a'
               }, (msXchar*4) );
               console.log("end colorea")

               // cada loop subir 1 el contador de caracteres, empezando en actualChar           
               actualChar += 1; 
               console.log("char actual " + actualChar);

               // y subir en msXchar ms el contador de tiempo
               actualTime += msXchar;

               // si el num de char actual es mayor que el largo total del texto, detenemos el intervalo, lo mismo si se ha pausado o terminado el audio
               if (actualChar > (durText)) {clearInterval(elInterval);
               console.log("interval cleared actualChar > durText");};
               elAudio.onpause = function(){clearInterval(elInterval);
               console.log("interval cleared paused");};
               elAudio.onended = function(){clearInterval(elInterval);
               console.log("interval cleared ended");};

            // repite este intervalcada msXchar ms
          }, msXchar); 

      };
   }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `animate` method will work async. not sync.
(Every `jQuery.fn.animate` creates its timer for animating.)

So, You need to clear not only timer but also animation queue.

### See References

`.animate(...)`: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

`.stop(...)`): https://api.jquery.com/stop/

`.finish(...)`: https://api.jquery.com/finish/

### Demo

http://codepen.io/mooyoul/pen/NxRJOr